# Feedparser Python : Is there a way to handle connection errors?

Tags: python, http-error, feedparser

I am talking about the HTTP errors, for instance "404 Not Found". I read the documentation but found nothing that could help me.

Comment: Could you add some small code snippet, and additional context on how you expect to "handle" a not found with the feedparser module  in your usage? Do you want to log the error, do you want to "autocorrect / guess" a similar url (i hope not ;-), ... want more "elegance in the process (catching of exceptional conditions etc.) ?

Answer (score 2):

Feedparser returns the HTTP status code in the `status` attribute (as documented at https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-status.html) which you can check and then handle however you need to:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> nonfeed = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/notafeed')
>>> nonfeed.status
404
>>> feed = feedparser.parse('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/')
>>> feed.status
200
```

See also the [documentation on "HTTP Redirects"](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/http-redirect.html). All HTTP headers are returned in the `headers` attribute, which can be useful for error reporting.

Even if there are no HTTP errors, there might be some parsing errors. While feedparser is very liberal in what it accepts, it does set a [bozo flag](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/bozo.html) if it encounters a malformed feed (and puts a description of the error in `bozo_exception`):

```
>>> feed.bozo
False
>>> nonfeed.bozo
1
>>> nonfeed.bozo_exception
SAXParseException('syntax error',)
```